# Using Join with update statemtent

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am having trouble with my query. I am trying to update the column "weighted_avg_2004" in an exiting table. I want to set that column equal to the product of two values, one in columns avg_2004 and one in column year_2004 (these two columns are in different tables).

```
Update #WeightedPercentChange
Set weighted_avg_2004 = (SELECT a.avg_2004 * b.year_2004
FROM #Average_PercentChange a
LEFT JOIN dbo.AnnualWeights b
ON a.SIZE = b.size)
```

I am receiving the following error:
"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."

Not sure why the subquery is returning more than one result. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `SUM`:

```
Update #WeightedPercentChange
Set weighted_avg_2004 = (SELECT SUM(a.avg_2004 * b.year_2004) / SUM(b.year_2004)
FROM #Average_PercentChange a
LEFT JOIN dbo.AnnualWeights b
ON a.SIZE = b.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.weighted_avg_2004 = (a.avg_2004 * b.year_2004)
FROM [#WeightedPercentChange] a LEFT JOIN dbo.AnnualsWeights b ON a.SIZE = b.size
```